# Using a variable with Get-ADComputer -filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, quotes

I might be overthinking this, but have been unable to get this simple code edit to work with Powershell

This works fine

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingsystem -like "Windows server 2012"
```

However, i'd like to use a variable such as $ServerOS = "Windows server 2022"

And then using that variable inside the same code, such as this

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingsystem -like "$EOLOS"
```

However, as the -filter uses 'single' quotes, it doesn't work. How would I edit the code to make the variable work?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingsystem -like "Windows server 2012"
```

Comment: Use single-quotes inside the string literal and remember to terminate with a balancing `"`: `Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingsystem -like '$EOLOS'"`

Comment: worth noting that `-like` is for wildcard search tho it translates to the same ldap syntax, you should use `-eq` in this case: `"operatingsystem -eq '$EOLOS'"`

Comment: If you do want to use embedded `"`, escape them as `\`"` (or `""`):  `"operatingsystem -eq \`"$EOLOS\`""`

Comment: Thx!  @MathiasR.Jessen, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to split the filter parameter, insert it into a variable and call the entire variable as the filter.

With your example you will get the following result:

```
$EOLOS='Windows server 2012'
$Filter='operatingsystem -like "*' + $EOLOS + '*"'
#Filter value: operatingsystem -like "*Windows server 2012*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter $Filter
```

However, in your case specificlly, it sounds like it is best to use equal (-eq) as it is an exact value (but it is yours to decide):

```
$EOLOS='Windows server 2012'
$Filter='operatingsystem -EQ "' + $EOLOS + '"'
#Filter value: operatingsystem -EQ "Windows server 2012"
Get-ADComputer -Filter $Filter
```